# C++ OpenGL wrapper: interface similar to fixed pipeline, can export .collada

Tags: c++, opengl

I have opengl code that uses the fixed pipeline.
Hitting two birds with one stone, I need a wrapper that can help me with the following tasks:

1. Convert the code to the new shader-based pipeline with minimal effort.
   I have a class that calls opengl functions, such as: glBegin(triangles/lines), glVertex, glPushMatrix, glTranslate, glColor, gluSphere.

Ideally, I'd like it to derive from a class that supplies these functions in the base class. Behind the scenes, it would use the same high level logic as the fixed pipeline.

2. I'd like to export an opengl scene to .collada to load in an external renderer.
   Opengl is low level rendering, and it doesn't have the concept of a scene. For example, this reddit post:

> "You realize that you have to write a shim to capture all API calls
> you are interested in to do that. Then, when finally, a draw call is
> emitted you have to parse every single vertex and collect the data
> from all over the memory from the buffers that you have recorded from
> the APi calls that set up VAOs, VBOs and IBOs. Then you have to parse
> the shader source code so that you can see which uniforms and vertex
> attributes contribute to vertex clip coordinate generation. Then you
> also have to synthesize/guess which outputs are normal, color, texture
> coordinate and so on from the shader source if the resulting program
> even have those in .obj file format-wise.
>
> This gets even more complicated if Compute is used to generate data
> inside the GPU for any of the buffers. If geometry or tessellator is
> used then you also have to implement one of those so that you get
> accurate outputs from the vertex processing. TL;DR - you have to write
> your own OpenGL 4.5 driver that does exactly the same things a real
> hardware driver would do. Good luck with that."

However, my scene is simple, using the fixed pipeline operations above.
I'd like the wrapper to keep track and construct a scene that can be exported.

--

EDIT: Since recommendation is off-topic, I'll ask the following question.
What I need above seems like something obvious that many should have found useful. Since I can't find a library that accomplishes that, I'm wondering if my approach is unreasonable?
More specifically, how do people port their legacy opengl code; do they write the relevant part from scratch, or does everyone implement his own wrapper as I suggested?
What about constructing a scene to export to collada?

Posted also:
https://community.khronos.org/t/c-opengl-wrapper-interface-similar-to-fixed-pipeline-can-export-collada/105829

Comment: qt: "I'm looking for a wrapper". I know how to do it, but it seems an obvious thing that many should have found useful already.

Comment: You have to wirte a "wrapper". Anyway questions about finding a tool or library are off-topic: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I rephrased my question.

Comment: "What I need above seems like something obvious that many should have found useful." Not it my book, at least. Fixed-function pipeline is dead since 15 years. And for scene export: in the real world, you either load external object data (so re-exporting it again is useless), or you generate data, and then, you know exactly what you generate, and can write a useful object fromat much more efficiently and directly than ny hooking into GL draw calls and gathering all the scattered bits and pieces from all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are some parts in legacy OpenGL that are not optimized in current drivers (like glDrawPixels, the raster drawing operations and indexed color mode), between modern hardware and the modest requirements of legacy applications, legacy OpenGL stuff runs well enough on modern systems.

The main reason to "modernize" legacy OpenGL code is, if one want to make use of the modern features. Any sort of "wrapper" will just run into the same kind of design problems that the OpenGL API ran between OpenGL-1.5 to OpenGL-2.1: Lots of built-in variables, default state, implicit action, etc. etc. This is difficult to document properly, and even more difficult to make use of reliably. Which is the reason you usually don't find these kinds of wrappers.

If you find yourself in the situation, that you absolutely must port your legacy code to modern OpenGL, e.g. to be interoperable with *core* contexts, then your best course of action will be to do a proper rewrite. Replace implcit mode calls to filling vertex buffers, replace calls to *glTexEnv…*, *glMaterial…*, *glLight…* with loading appropriate shaders and setting their uniforms.

Or, if you want a quick and dirty method: Just create two contexts, a modern one, and a legacy one and switch between them; often you can establish "list" sharing between them.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I accepted the answer since it technically answered my question. Nevertheless, I disagree: i) I'm not looking for a perfect library, and my requirements were quite basic. ii) quick&dirty is my only reasonable option; replacing everything all at once is impractical. iii) quick&dirty is what I suggested. iv) 15 years? I wasn't even aware of the shaders pipeline up until two years ago.